# Cast instance in list to its generic interface

Tags: c#, oop, generics, interface

I have a list of instances BasicReference and TaggableReference, that implements a generic interface IReference

BasicReference.cs

```
namespace DefaultNamespace
{
    public class BasicReference : IReference<string>
    {
        public string Resolve(string name)
        {
            return name;
        }

        public bool Valid(string name)
        {
            return (name != null);
        }
    }
}
```

TaggableReference.cs

```
namespace DefaultNamespace
{
    public class TaggableReference : IReference<(string,string)>
    {
        public (string,string) Resolve(string name)
        {
            return (name + "1",name + "2");
        }

        public bool Valid(string name)
        {
            return (name != null);
        }
    }
}
```

IReference.cs

```
namespace DefaultNamespace
{
    public interface IReference<out T>
    {
        T Resolve(string name);
        bool Valid(string name);
    }
}
```

I can add BasicReference and TaggableReference to a list where Type parameter is object. But how do i cast them to call the methods from IReference? And what type do I return from the method?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DefaultNamespace
{
    public class Test
    {
        private List<object> references = new List<object>();

        public ??? Test()
        {
            references.Add(new BasicReference());
            references.Add(new TaggableReference());

            string referenceExample = "example";

            foreach (var reference in references)
            {
                // How can I cast this so I can call IReference methods and return the type
                // What type do I return from method?
                if (reference.Valid(referenceExample))
                {
                    ??? result = reference.Resolve(referenceExample);    
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you expect the `Test()` method to be called? Knowing that might help understand how to structure the code

Comment: I would want Test to return the type returned either from Basic Reference or TaggableReference. Basically I need to be able say its either a string or Tuple of string string.

Comment: `IReference<(string,string)>` is completely different from `IReference<string>` so, so you need to check it first: `if (obj is IReference<string> iRefStr) iRefStr.Valid("test");`

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the type you're expecting when calling the `Test()` method, you can make that method generic as well and return the reference for the given type:

```
public T Test<T>()
{
    references.Add(new TaggableReference());
    references.Add(new BasicReference());

    string referenceExample = "example";

    foreach (var reference in references.OfType<IReference<T>>())
    {
        if (reference.Valid(referenceExample))
        {
            return reference.Resolve(referenceExample);
        }
    }

    return default; // Handle type not found accordingly
}
```

The usage of this would be:

```
var reference = test.Test<string>();
Console.WriteLine(reference);

var taggableReference = test.Test<(string, string)>();
Console.WriteLine(taggableReference);
```

Which produces the expected output:

[image]